# Is there any impact of sp_updatestats in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I am going to execute `sp_updatestats` on production DB, just want to confirm is there any impact of it? Will my DB get bit faster due to this?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Product specific issue.) Also, give a much better explanation/description.

Comment: `sp_updatestats` may effect the performance if your database is in operational mode with big data, usually we schedule it when there is no load on the database

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx

Comment: *and really my DB will get bit faster due to this?*: Not necessarily, it's not magic.  If your current stats are stale though, then yes, the SQL Server engine will be able to make more accurate decisions as to how to execute the queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may see

1. [An increase in IO activity](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/01/update-statistics-the-secret-io-explosion/)

2.[TempDB usage may growup little bit](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/linchi_shea/archive/2009/08/16/performance-impact-tempdb-and-update-stats.aspx)

According [to this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19333/update-statistics-with-full-scan),SCH-S lock will be taken,so any activity trying to change table structure also will be blocked..(I don't have a Server to test right now)

> really my DB will get bit faster due to this?

Updating statistics will help SQLServer in getting accurate estimates,there by good plans..